# How can I perform a SSO using SAML in php?

Tags: php, single-sign-on, saml, simplesamlphp

I'm having problems when developing a SSO to a 3rd party server using simplesamlphp.

I installed SimpleSAMLphp in the server. Then I've set the IdP as https://openidp.feide.no and the entityID SP as the 3rd party server. I've set the metadata correctly, but the response message is an error.

After checking the configuration the 3rd party sent me, I noticed that they specified that I should indicate in the subject of the xml orgdir=xxx;ecid=xxx

Using SimpleSAMLphp, how can I do this? Thanks in advance

Comment: It's unclear to me what you are trying to do, and what kind of error you get. Can you elaborate more on the question? Why not just let the 3rd party server authenticate directly against Feide OpenIdP?

Comment: I'm trying to sign in existing users in my platform to this 3rd party server using SAML authentication, first time I'm using SAML though

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You do not need to set up an IdP yourself if you are using an upstream IdP, such as Feide OpenIdP. Just register the urls from the 3rd party server's metadata directly in OpenIdP.

Comment: thanks for answering Jorn, I did that already, but the 3rd party server told me I have to specify in the subject 2 parameters, and that's what I don't know how to do it.